# c inline assembly loading a register value to esp register

Tags: c, pointers, x86, cygwin, inline-assembly

In a code, I have following declaration

```
#if GCC == 1
#define SET_STACK(s)    asm("movl temp,%esp");
...
#endif
```

In the code, exactly at one place, this macro is used, on which line compiler indicates of `undefined reference to 'temp'`.

```
temp = (int*)some_pointer;
SET_STACK(temp);
```

the `temp` variable is declared as global volatile void pointer

```
volatile void* temp;
```

Is there any syntax problem with the inline assembly ?
As of my understanding, the inline assembly tries to load the value of `temp` (not the dereferenced value , but the pointer itself)

Comment: Is there a ; at the end of #define? Never seen one before

Comment: @UnderDog: The semicolon is not after the define, it is part of the value of the macro. If you use `SET_STACK` macro, the `asm` instruction will be inserted, including the semicolon.

Comment: @mastov: Yes, but that is wrong and can break a conditional statement.

Comment: @Olaf: Yes, considering the way it is used, it is unnecessary (wouldn't say "wrong" - you just have to be aware of it). Just saying, the semicolon has nothing to do with the syntax of the `#define` directive. And depending on what you are planning on doing, you might even need the semicolon.

Comment: @mastov: Unless you encllodes the whole macro body, including the selmicolon into parenthetized braces (gcc special), it is definitively an invitation to disaster for a function-like macro. You're welcome to prove me wrong.

Comment: @Olaf: Sure, it's certainly dangerous for this kind. My point was to explain that the semicolon didn't have anything to do with the `#define` syntax and that it *can* have a purpose.

Comment: @mastov: (no discussion about the "`#define` syntax", I did not even mention that. "...  it can have a purpose": Still waiting for an example. The only purpose for semicolon here is to make an expression a statement. And as that is already given by the "caller", there would be two of them actually. _What purpose_ can two adjacent semicolons have (except causing trouble)?

Comment: @Olaf: See http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/overview_events.html#overview_events_eventtables You declare an event table in an abstract way without knowing what those macros do internally. So there is no way to know from the outside, where a semicolon should or shouldn't be placed. You leave that to those macros. Some of them (like `wxEND_EVENT_TABLE`), of course, have to include a semicolon in the end because they consist of class or method declarations that need to be terminated by a semicolon.

Comment: @mastov: "... for a function-like macro." Your example is 1st for C++ and 2nd not "function-like". I  did not talk about other macros; used some myself already for such purposes. Never mind, This leads nowhere.

Comment: @Olaf: I agreed before about function-like macros ("Sure, it's certainly dangerous for this kind."). I've never talked about any specific macro type. All I ever said was that a semicolon at the end of a macro definition can have its purpose.

Comment: Altering ESP in inline assembler results in undefined behaviour, you should not do this.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use extended assembler to pass C operands to the assembler: Read the [manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.2/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#Extended-Asm). (Note: as you did not specify which version you are using, I just picked one).

Do not forget to add registers used in the assembler into the *clobber list*. You should also make the assembler `asm volatile`.

Depending on your execution environment, it might be a very bad idea to manually manipulate the stack pointer! At least you should put that into a `__attribute__((naked))` function, not a macro. The trailing `;` in the macro is definitively wrong, you will have that already right after the macro (2 semicolons might break conditional statements!

Comment: `You should also make the assembler asm volatile` ,is that mean asm volatile("assembly instructions") ?

Comment: Note: use quotation marks to quote, not backticks - these are for code fragments. For the question: sure.

Comment: While you just 'picked' a version, the [newer](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.1.0/gcc/Extended-Asm.html) docs are significantly improved.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd: 5.1 is actually not used that much for production development. Reason I picked 4.8.2 is partly random, but also because it is standard with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Comment: That is a good point for the docs in general, but not so much for the inline asm.  All the new docs do is better describe functionality that has been there for a long time.  The 4.x docs did a *horrible* job describing the feature and how to use it.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd: Just read my note! Apparently, you **did** find a newer version; use that and be happy! This discussion is just useless.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use C variables in GCC inline assembly, you have to make use of the [Extended ASM syntax](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html), e.g.:

```
volatile int temp = 0;
asm("movl %0,%%esp"
  : /* No outputs. */
  : "rm" (temp)
);
```

Comment: Thanks, but in SHARC inline assemblies, I used c variables with a `_` prepended, sucn as `var` would be used as `_var`, does this inline assembly and assembly syntax is specific to assemblers ? Is there syntax depending on assemblers ? (I read in GAS manuals about Intel syntax, and AT&T syntax)

Comment: There is not necessarily need to have `temp ` `volatile`. Leave that to the caller if required. Note that `volatile` prevents it to be a registers.

Comment: @nmxprime: How could inline-assembler be the same for different CPUs? SHARC is actually an DSP, which has quite a different architecture from normal CPUs. For the `asm` keyword and its semantics: Read the gcc manual, that is a gcc-specific extension. Doesn't this imply it is non-standard?

Comment: What is the point of using '+' instead of '='?  The asm doesn't read the existing value, it just overwrites it.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd: It does read the value of `temp`, in order to copy it to `%esp`.

Comment: Oops!  My bad.  Long time intel asm user which does the reverse.  In that case, why is temp an output instead of an input?

Comment: @DavidWohlferd: Because I made a mistake ;-). Edited.